# Ad Free Video Streaming to Web

Tags: streaming

I'm currently working with a charity that broadcasts our event to the web. The event is about a week long (24 hrs per day), and gets in excess of 2000 viewers at times during the stream.

I am wondering what the best free/low cost option is for streaming to the web that presents no ads to the viewers?

Answer (score 2):

Wowza Media Server on Amazon EC2 is a really cost-effective way to do it, it's very popular among churches because of its on-demand nature and low cost. You spin up the server when you need it, pay a small hourly charge for it, pay for the bandwidth used, and shut it down.

Answer (score 1):

You might try justin.tv

but since its a bigger thing you want to stream and streaming bandwith is very expensive it will end sooner or later in a paid solution.

livestream.com or watershed.ustream.tv could be interesting Hosts then.

But if you find some cheap to free alternative without (much) advertisement, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

bandwith is the only expensive thing in this setup. Setting up a streamingserver like wowaza or nginx and stream the data there is no big deal. but if you expect a greater amount of viewers you might think of a "small cdn" setup to distribute it.

since you wrote it's for a charity I would suggest to ask some companies for a sponsoring or special rates.